# How to include columns in groupby that is not present in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

This dataframe is categorized in A and B.

and I want to count values based on standard value "0", ">0" and nan.

Pls see the Cateogory A.
There isn't  'nan' data.

```
df :
Category    A      A      A       B       B 
CODE       U-01   U-02   U-03    U-04    U-05
n1          0      1      0       2       nan
n2          1      1      0       nan     nan
n3          3      0      0       0       2
```

In the Code,

```
df1 = (df.unstack()
         .mask(lambda x: x.gt(0), '>0')
         .fillna('nan')
         .groupby(level=[0, 2])
         .value_counts()
         .unstack([0,2], fill_value=0)
         .rename(columns={0:'0'}))
```

The output drop Category A & nan columns.
I want to express to every columns in "0, >0, nan".

```
Category           A           B
Standard           0    >0     0    >0     nan 
 n1                2     1     0     1      1
 n2                1     2     0     0      2
 n3                1     1     1     1      0
```

My desired output table would look like:

```
Category                 A                   B
Standard           0    >0    nan      0    >0     nan 
 n1                2     1     0       0     1      1
 n2                1     2     0       0     0      2
 n3                1     1     0       1     1      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by all possible combinations created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df1 = (df.unstack()
         .mask(lambda x: x.gt(0), '>0')
         .fillna('nan')
         .groupby(level=[0, 2])
         .value_counts()
         .unstack([0,2], fill_value=0)
         .rename(columns={0:'0'})
         )

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels[0], ['0','>0','nan']])
df1 = df1.reindex(mux, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df1)
Category  A         B       
          0 >0 nan  0 >0 nan
n1        2  1   0  0  1   1
n2        1  2   0  0  0   2
n3        2  1   0  1  1   0
```

Or you can reshape by `stack` and `unstack` with convert missing values to `0`:

```
df1 = (df.unstack()
         .mask(lambda x: x.gt(0), '>0')
         .fillna('nan')
         .groupby(level=[0, 2])
         .value_counts()
         .unstack([0,2], fill_value=0)
         .rename(columns={0:'0'})
         .stack()
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int)
         .unstack()
         )


print (df1)
Category  A         B       
          0 >0 nan  0 >0 nan
n1        2  1   0  0  1   1
n2        1  2   0  0  0   2
n3        2  1   0  1  1   0
```